# Font selector drop-list missing from Freehand MX under Wine

Tags: wine, fonts, interface

I am testing an old abandonware application Macromedia Freehand MX under Wine, which is a vector graphics editor. It seems to work mostly fine. However, the font selector drop-list is missing from the section with Text Properties:

[image]

This is how it looks under a Windows 7 virtual machine:

[image]

So, is there any chance to fix this?

My host OS is Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS.
wine-5.0 (Ubuntu 5.0-3ubuntu1)

Microsoft Fonts were just installed, but it did not make any difference.

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details for your Ubuntu system, I suspect it's related to whatever fonts you have (*or don't have installed*) on your *unstated* HOST OS; have you installed the Microsoft Fonts on your system for example?  (eg. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/Microsoft_Fonts)

Comment: It is Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS. The Microsoft Fonts installation did not fix the issue.

Comment: If you just installed the *Microsoft Fonts*, did you ensure the *font cache* was rebuilt?  (`fc-cache`) and ensure the new cache or list of available fonts were available (*may require logout/login; but I'm guessing here as I haven't used `wine` in decade+*)

Comment: The fc-cache command was executed. However, how to ensure that the new list of fonts is available?

Comment: I just operated a `sudo fc-cache -sv` on my system, and as it processed the various fonts I have installed (*all mine are in system directories*) I can see their inclusion... and at the end it's a  "*fc-cache: succeeded*" message. That tells me those fonts will be available to any app now requesting them (*that hasn't already accessed & cached it's own older copy; why I suggested logout/login so at least your desktop knows of update!*)  The logout/login is because many apps often peruse what's available at startup (ie. when first run, thus don't detect new fonts added*)

Comment: I got the  "fc-cache: succeeded" message. Can confirm that. However, the restart of the computer did not fix the issue. The field continues to stay blank...

Comment: That's all I can provide... there are different types of font files (*ttf,, otf, & many others*) with many older font types no longer used (*an OS/2 font type comes to mind as example being common with NT4/5/2000*) so you may need to add the types used by that program of that day (*that windows 7 may include for backwards compatibility for older windows versions, where Ubuntu provides only files used by older Ubuntu versions*) but I can't be more helpful here, and it may also be something else where you'll need others to aid with ideas/solutions anyway.

Comment: Thanks guiverc for trying!